# How to compare values between columns in 2 DataFrames in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, isin

I have 2 DataFrames in Python Pandas like below:

**Input:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["APPLE", "BANANA", "ORANGE"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col_x":["APPLEXX", "BANANA", "CARROT"]})
```

df1:

```
col1
------
APPLE
ORANGE
BANANA
```

df2:

```
col_x
--------
APPLEXX
BANANA
CARROT
```

**Requirements:**

And I need to print only rows from df2 (col_x), which: contain values from df1 (col1) as part or all of the value in df2 (col_x) and their equivalent in df1 (col1)

**Desire output:**

So, as an output I need something like below:

| col1 | col_x |
| --- | --- |
| APPLE | APPLEXX |
| BANANA | BANANA |

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: how large are those dataframes?

Comment: around 1k rows in df1 and a few hundred in df2

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [`assignment expressions`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) (since python 3.8) and builtin [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) method on generator expression:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[s, w] for w in df2['col_x']
                   if (s := next((x for x in df1['col1'] if x in w), None))])
print(df)
```

---

```
        0        1
0   APPLE  APPLEXX
1  BANANA   BANANA
```

---

For older python versions use the following generator function:

```
def match_gen(s1, s2):
    for word in s1:
        match = next((x for x in s2 if x in word), None)
        if match:
            yield (match, word)

df = pd.DataFrame(match_gen(df2['col_x'], df1['col1']))
```

Comment: I have error about syntax --> SyntaxError: invalid syntax in this line  if (s := next((x for x in df1['col1'] if x in w), None))]) in ":="

Comment: @dingaro, in my description I've written "since python 3.8"

Comment: Maybe do yo uhave solution for python below 3.8 ? :)